# Previewing and Typing in Unicode font (Private Area / Basic Multilingual Plane) in Linux for SMuFL

Tags: linux, fonts

I would like to make a change to an open source Android app which uses the [Bravura](https://github.com/steinbergmedia/bravura) font implementing the [Standard Music Font Layout (SMuFL) fonts](https://www.smufl.org/). I am developing on Linux.

The app displays musical notes with things like

```
<string name="notef_c5">&#xe020; &#xe01a;&#xe050;&#xe014;=&#xe014;=&#xe014;&#xeb90;&#xe1d5; &#xe014;=&#xe014;=&#xe034;</string>
```

which is displayed like
[image: middle C]

I now need to change things and I would like to see what I am going to do, rather than semi-randomly changing the Unicode numbers and see what happens. So I installed the font on my Linux desktop from github, by simply copying the [SVG](https://github.com/steinbergmedia/bravura/tree/master/redist/svg) that the app is using into my global font directory and that did not work (`fc-cache` said `/usr/share/fonts/svg/Bravura: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs`). The same procedure for the [OTF](https://github.com/steinbergmedia/bravura/tree/master/redist/otf) did work. This could be a problem down the line, since the app is using slightly modified version of the SVG, so any hint on that could help, but it's secondary regarding the question.

In fact I want to use "something" to display the font, and I tried many things, including Charmap and FontManager (which is almost the same as FontViewer). Charmap is the worst, displaying basically every single font installed on the machine even if I select just the Bravura (why is that???!)  -- FontManager does the same (???!) -- FontViewer is almost passable, in that (when the "Characters" tab is selected) it display empty squares for the characters not defined in Bravura. Therefore with lots of careful scrolling it displays the "actual things" I am looking for, but it does not show their unicode values, and it's an extenuating search of few actual characters in a huge ocean of empty squares. So it's a no go anyway.

Is it possible that the best solution is just to blindly type Unicode values as [described in the docs](https://github.com/steinbergmedia/bravura/blob/master/redist/bravura-text.md) and see what happens? I know, if I were running Windows or Mac I could use [Dorico SE](https://new.steinberg.net/dorico/se/) but more generally there must be a better way of using Unicode in Linux, perhaps built for other purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking for specific symbols in the SMuFL specification, the full list of glyphs is available on the [SMuFL website](https://www.smufl.org/version/latest/). (Note that the fonts themselves know nothing about music typesetting, they are simply collections of shapes to be used by a typesetting program. Even the simple example you provided is a composite of several carefully scaled and positioned glyphs, and simply changing the character codes may or may not work as intended.)

If you’re looking for ways to input Unicode characters on Linux, see the many suggestions provided here: [How to type special characters in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You can display any font with [Fontforge](https://fontforge.org). For a SMuFL font like Bravura you can find the glyphs in the 'Private Use Area' starting at E000.
[image]